# Dishwasher - 3/8 inch 90° elbow leaks. How do I tighten it without overtighting it and it is pointing down?

Tags: dishwasher

I've installed a new dishwasher, but the 3/8 inch 90° elbow leaks.

How do I tighten it without overtightening it and it is pointing down?

I put two wraps of teflon tape and hand tightened it, and tightened with a wrench about 3/4 turn.

Thanks for any advice or tips.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try tightening the elbow more. You don't usually have to worry about over tightening brass on brass, You can torque them pretty good. If the fitting doesn't point down, so be it, it needs to be tight.

Answer (score 2):

If you can not get that elbow to stop leaking, try RTV silicone on the threads instead of the teflon tape and wait a couple days to use the washer.

Answer (score -1):

Just redo the ptfe and put more layers - most common error is people skimp on the tape as they think it is expensive, also make it have more layers towards the middle.

PTFE is not Pull Tight (it’s) F... Expensive.